# Run script instead of opening Application (xdg-mime, gvfs-mime)

Tags: bash, scripts, remote, transmission, xdg-open

following this little hack, my goal is to upload any magnet link to my "remote" Desktop PC: https://blog.flo.cx/2011/02/how-to-open-magnet-links-on-a-remote-transmission-daemon-with-one-click/

Unfortunately the Guide is from 2011 and uses gconftools which does not work on my machine. From what I understand my Ubuntu 14.04 with Unity uses xdg-mime and/or gvfs-mime to set the desired action, but everything I tried so far did not work and google didn't give any results concerning scripts. man pages did't help me either. :/

Can anyone more experienced with this mime stuff help me get the right command?

TL;DR: What I want is to set the default action for magnet links to running a script instead of opening transmission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the use of .desktop files, I finally got it working. Here is my solution:

1. create script to upload magnet link to PC running transmission:

```
test -z $1 && echo "need magnet link!" && exit
HOST=
PORT=
USER=
PASS=#apparently ";" does not work
LINK="$1"
#add torrent paused?
#PAUSED="true"
PAUSED="false"
SESSID=$(curl --silent --anyauth --user $USER:$PASS "http://$HOST:$PORT/transmission/rpc" | sed 's/.*//g;s/.*//g')
curl --silent --anyauth --user $USER:$PASS --header "$SESSID" "http://$HOST:$PORT/transmission/rpc" -d "{\"method\":\"torrent-add\",\"arguments\":{\"paused\":${PAUSED},\"filename\":\"${LINK}\"}}"
```

[sorry, the formatting is horrible. can't get it to work. `"<code>"` and other chars inside the codeblock get interpreted and are NOT DISPLAYED. please check the link for full script code: https://blog.flo.cx/2011/02/how-to-open-magnet-links-on-a-remote-transmission-daemon-with-one-click/ ]

2. create .desktop file which executes the above script and place the file in /usr/share/applications/:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=MagnetLinkTransfer
Comment=executes script to upload magnet link to desktop pc
Exec=/home/username/MagnetLinkTransfer.sh %u
Icon=utilities-terminal
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=Application;
```

note the %u as argument for execute script!

3. set action/application for xdg-open

```
xdg-mime default MagnetLinkTransfer.desktop x-scheme-handler/magnet
gvfs-mime --set x-scheme-handler/magnet MagnetLinkTransfer.desktop
```